# Why lambda removes cv and ref?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer, return-type-deduction

Given a lambda:

```
auto f = [](const T& var){ return var; };
```

Why return type of `f` is `T` (not `const T&`)? Where is this in the Standard?

Comment: Note that you can use `[](const T& var) -> const auto&` to get a `const&` return type.

Answer (score 5):

The point is:

1. The use of auto for return type deduction employ template type deduction rule.
2. The return type is delcared as passed-by-value; which means that the reference-ness and top-level cv-qualifiers of expression used for deduction (i.e. `var`) are ignored.

Quotes from the standard:

About [auto](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-4):

> If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type T' replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. Obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a new invented type template parameter U or, if the initialization is copy-list-initialization, with std::initializer_list. Deduce a value for U using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call ([temp.deduct.call]), where P is a function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is e. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, T' is obtained by substituting the deduced U into P.

About the rule of [template argument deduction from a function call](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#2):

> If P is not a reference type:
>
> - If A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of A's type are ignored for type deduction.

About [reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#5):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

So for `var`(i.e. `A`) is `const T&`, the deduced return type would be `T` here.

Answer (score 4):

This is a much more fundamental issue about C++. Nothing to do with specifically with lambdas or `auto`.

In C++, a reference behaves the same as a non-reference in almost all situations. This is deliberate, and is based on the idea that a reference to an object really should be equivalent to the object itself. In the following code, there is no real difference between `x` and `y`:

```
int x  = 3;
int &y = x;
```

In fact, it is impossible to distinguish them (except via `decltype`). The are both lvalues of type `int`. If you call `foo(x)` and `foo(y)`, the compiler will treat them both as having the same type and value category and therefore the same overload is selected.

I would interpret `x` and `y` by saying that both of them are references to the same object. They are two different 'names' for the same object.

Therefore `return x` and `return y` are equivalent to each other, and therefore the lambda won't care about the `&` when deducing its return type.

This explains why the `&` is ignored. C++ tries to "ignore" the `&` as much as possible, precisely in order that references can be treated as fully equivalent to the original object.

Now that it is established that we are returning by value, not by reference, then we can understand why the `const` is also ignored. A copy of an object doesn't need to be `const`. Consider this in reverse also: we can pass a `const int` argument as an `int` parameter of a function.

Comment: Careful... There's no such thing as a "reference object"; a reference is not an object. Also, both calls to `foo` will be ambiguous in your example. And, while the answer can be seen as a non-language-lawyer rationale for dropping the `&`, it doesn't explain why `const` is dropped.

Comment: Thanks @bogdan, I should have tested my overload set. I've made a few tweaks. I guess it's still not an ideal answer, but I do think it's useful to emphasize that this design isn't just something that was written into the C++11 "from thin air" in 2011, and that it instead represents a consistent design throughout C++ that references should usually behave identically to the object they are referencing (including having the same type and value category).

Answer (score 2):

Return type deduction of `auto` return functions with no trailing return type in C++11 or 14 is done as if you did

```
auto retval = /* return expression */
```

and `auto` *always* deduces a value type.

Lambdas are the only `auto` return functions in C++11.   In C++14 it was extended to other functions (following similar rules).

In C++11 you can fix this with a `->decltype(var)` or a `->int const&` trailing return type on your lambda.

In C++14 you can simply `->decltype(auto)`, which changes the return type deduction rules from

```
auto retval = /* return expression */
```

to be more like

```
decltype(/* return expression */) retval = /* return expression */
```

which, in your case, means not dropping the `&` or the `const`.

Note that returning `const&` parameters is exceedingly dangerous, as rvalues can be turned into `const&` implicitly, and reference lifetime extension does not commute past a function call.  So:

```
auto&& x = some_function();
// or
int const& x = some_function();
```

is safe even if `some_function()` returns a temporary, while assuming `f` behaves the way you want `f` to behave:

```
auto&& x = f( some_function() );
// or
int const& x = f( some_function() );
```

generates `x` a dangling reference to the temporary returned by `some_function()`.

This can break things surprisingly, like the fact that `for(:)` loops implicitly use `auto&&` parameters behind the scene, and clean up temporaries between the initialization of the range expression and the execution of the iteration.

This answer is not yet complete, as I have not added references into the standard.